# Youtube iframe on Android Webview: forcing high quality

Tags: javascript, android, iframe, webview, youtube

I am working on an app that requires me to use a webview to display youtube videos. I can't use the Youtube API so no need to give me suggestions about that, I am doing a lot of heavy processing on the video being displayed with a lot of overwriting, and it's possible using a webview, not with the extremely rigid youtube API that one can't even extend.

To the main issue: I need youtube to play the video in the highest quality available using an iframe to embed the youtube video in a webview. The embed guidelines using JS don't work on Android, I tried it and it's working great on a computer, but not on Android. I have tried everything from the "vq=" parameters (don't know if those still work, doubt it) to using javascript, but there is no way to get the quality to go up, the maximum I get looks more like some kind of 480p if not 360p, which is extremely handicaping the whole app.

I'm getting a bit desperate here, if anyone has any suggestions to try I would be very thankful.

Comment: I know this isn't the answer you want to hear, but hear me out since I went down this rabbit hole some years ago. Yes, you CAN use youtube in a webview, but as you're finding out right now, there are many many limitations. You might be able to get pass this currently issue you're having, but then you will be blocked by another one, and another one, and another one. I would strongly suggest you to learn the youtube API instead, and continue from there. There are also many open source libraries for Android that make the API much easier to use.

Comment: Thanks TooManyEduardos, I actually know how to use the youtube API and have worked with it quite a lot before, but it just is too limited to perform what I want. If only I could at least render into my own TextureView. As I said I am doing some heavy processing on the video (heavy real time warping, scaling, duplicating into multiple views etc..) Can you inform me about the open source libraries? I might be able to use them.